# Converting text dumped in textfile to Csv and Array

Tags: java, string, csv, text-files

i have been using an `actionListener`to pass text from numerous `TextFields` into a text file named `writetouser.txt`this works fine though i have noticed that this text is just dumped and is not in the format of an array. For the purposes of this application it is necessary that i am able to search this text file and show values based on searches entered. I have a file which reads the data from the text file and have attempted to convert the data to `CSV`'s so it is is readable as an array. i am wondering what must be entered instead of user, pass in order to take the text from inside the file`writetouser.txt`.

Addendum:

```
public void ReadUser()
 {
  try{
// Open the file
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("writetouser.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
//Read File Line By Line
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  //System.out.println (strLine);

    String[] items = strLine.split(",");
    String[][] usersArray = new String [10][2];

    for (String item : items) {
       System.out.println(item);
    }
}
       //Close the input stream
in.close();
}catch (Exception e){
    //Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

}
}

here is an example of the data which i am trying to separate. it is entered into textfile as

```
 inputUser = user + ", " + pass;
 writetouser.WriteToUser(inputUser);
```

dburgess, 2345

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide us an an example of the data you're trying to read.

Comment: The Addendum above shows an example of the data as well as the method in which posts it is passed to the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing my code i noticed that the two pieces of code below were doing the exact same thing which is why i was being presented with each piece of info twice.

A

```
 for (String item : items) {...}
```

B

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    String item = items[i];
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
String[] items = strLine.split(",");
```

Comment: i had previously tried this but i am only presented with the top line of my text file as username but no password separation. also an exception is caught and error message is shown.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that this line is commented out:

```
//System.out.println (strLine);
```

Which suggests to me that you were probably trying to ensure that you're getting the line you expect from your file.  If you **are** getting what you expect, we're clear to move on.  If not, there's a problem in how the file is being read, or the data isn't formatted how you expect.

If we're good so far, we've arrived at the problem of parsing and displaying the content of the file.  I'm assuming that you're trying to write the contents of the file to your terminal and expecting one format, but getting another.

**I think what you'll see right now is something like this:**

```
Username: dburgess
Password: 2345
```

(with no more than 1 username/password pair printed).

**And I'm guessing you want something like this:**

```
Username: dburgess       Password: 2345
Username: someOtherUser  Password: SomeOtherpass
Username: blahblah       Password: etcPass
....
Username: thelastOne     Password: Icanhazpassword?
```

There are a lot of assumptions there (I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to do) -- if those assumptions are correct, let me know; I'll post some formatting tips.

Comment: Your assumptions are indeed correct. i have since removed some of the code which you will can see in the Addendum above and i now presented with my full array in form of a list with no Username: or Password: although your layout appears better so hints would be appreciated.